# Modify a C# Class to be a Collection

Tags: c#, constructor

Below is a `Person` class. Currently, it can only be used to instantiate a single `Person` object. I would like to change it so it can accept a list of full names and result in a collection of `Person` objects.

```cs
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName;
        public string Organization;

        public Person(string Organization, string FullName)
        {
            this.FullName = FullName;
            this.Organization = Organization;
        }
    }
}
```

This would ideally be similar to the [`Fileinfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0). This class can be initialized by either providing a single file name or a list of file names. I would also like to be able to initialize this `Person` class to be constructed using either a list of full names or a single name.

Comment: Where will it get the 'list of FullName' ?  You code doesnt quite match the title - a collection class would require such a collection be available to it.  And it ought to have a plural name - `People` to help make clear what it is anf what it doies

Comment: Your going to need to flesh out your question some more. If you have an array (or other type of collection) you can just return it in the same way you'd return a string. But, we don't see any collection in your code or your question

Comment: The best way to approach a class that can accept a single name or a list of names is to just make it a collection. That collection can have zero, one, or more elements in it. You can use conditions on the constructor to prevent it from having zero items, if that's a requirement. Regardless, you end up with something like: `public class People: Collection<Person> { … }`

Comment: How would an initializer be written?  I have not been able to get it to work.  I stared the initializer with `public People(string Organization, string[] FullName)'

Comment: @Robert: As it's now clear what you're asking, I've reopened this question so that I can provide a full answer with more comprehensive examples. If that helps, please be sure to accept my answer by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer. If it doesn't, let me know why, and I'll see if I can adjust to your requirements.

Comment: So you want a static factory method? `public static ICollection<People> CreatePeople(string org, string[] names){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `FileInfo` class works the way you're expecting—but I now understand what you're asking. As mentioned in the comments, you're going to need *two* classes. The first one is for your business object—in this case `Person`. The second one will be a collection-based class, such as `PersonCollection`.

As an alternative, you can alter your data model so that you have a separate `Organization` and `Person` class. In that model, your `Person` class would have a `FullName` property, but not an `Organization` property. I'll address that option at the end.

Instead of just offering code, I'll attempted to explain the concepts as I go, while also flagging issues you're likely going to run into along the way. That makes for a longer post. But given the nature of the question, I hope this additional detail will prove valuable.

### Business Object

Your `Person` class can continue to operate *exactly* the way you've proposed. That said, there are a couple of improvements you might consider.

First, if your business object is never going to be modified after you've instantiated it—i.e., it's *immutable*—then you can use the C# 9.0 record syntax, which allows your constructor to define properties directly:

```cs
public record Person(string Organization, string FullName);
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to keep this as a class, then I'd recommend implementing it as follows:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public Person(string organization, string fullName)
    {
        Organization = organization;
        FullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- I've used the [auto-implemented property syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) for `Organization` and `FullName`; otherwise, they will be treated as public *fields*, which have slightly different semantics ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/field)).
- I've updated your parameter names to be `camelCase`, so you don't need to assign property values with the `this` prefix. This is standard in C#.
- I think it's more intuitive for the `fullName` to be your first parameter, but that's a stylistic preference, so I've kept this consistent with your original code.

### Collection-Based Class

There are a number of ways to create a strongly typed collection-based class. The easiest is to simply inherit from `Collection<Person>`:

```cs
public class PersonCollection: Collection<Person>
{
    public PersonCollection(params Person[] people)
    {
        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            Add(person);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- You could also call this `People`, as I did in the comments, but Microsoft recommends that strongly typed collection classes start with the item type (i.e., `Person`) and end with `Collection` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections#naming-custom-collections)).
- You could also derive from e.g., `List<Person>`, but Microsoft recommends using the more familiar `Collection<>` class ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections#implementing-custom-collections)).
- The `params` keyword allows you to accept an *array*—in this case of `Person` objects—but pass them as a list of *parameters*, instead of an array ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)). This makes for a friendlier and more intuitive interface in this case.
- You could instead accept an array of strings—e.g., `fullNames`—in order to construct a new `Person` object for each one, as you requested. But as your current `Person` object *also* needs an `Organization` parameter, it's easier to first construct the `Person` object, and then pass it to the collection.

### Usage

You can now construct the class by creating some `Person` instances and passing them to the `PersonCollection` constructor as follows:

```cs
//Construct some Person objects
var robert = new Person("Robert, Inc.", "Robert");
var jeremy = new Person("Ignia, LLC", "Jeremy")

//Construct a new PersonCollection
var people = new PersonCollection(robert, jeremy);
```

Alternatively, if you're using C# 9.0 (e.g., with .NET 5+), and are hard-coding your `Person` initializers, you can also use the following syntactical shorthand:

```cs
var people = new PersonCollection(
  new ("Robert, Inc.", "Robert"),
  new ("Ignia, LLC", "Jeremy")
);
```

This looks *similar* to your request to pass in a list of full names—except that it accounts for your `Organization` property, and results in a full `Person` object for each. If you'd truly prefer to just pass in an array of names, see *Organization-Based Model* at the end of this answer.

### Validation

In practice, you probably want to add in some validation to ensure that each `Person` reference is not null, and that *at least* one `Person` instance is passed to your constructor. If so, you can extend this to include some validation. Here's one possible approach to that:

```cs
public class PersonCollection: Collection<Person>
{
    public PersonCollection(params Person[] people)
    {
        foreach (var person in people?? Array.Empty<Person>())
        {
            if (person is null) 
            {
                continue;
            }
            Add(person);
        }
        if (Count == 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(people));
        }
    }
}
```

I default to the `Array.Empty<Person>` on the loop so that we don't need to do two checks—first for the `people` length, and then for the `PersonCollection` length. But you can adjust to your preferences.

### Organization-Based Model

In the comments, [you proposed an alternate constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69240050/modify-a-c-sharp-class-to-be-a-collection/69321053#comment122464301_69240050):

```cs
public People(string Organization, string[] FullName) { … }
```

This implies a different data model. If you're going to have one organization that can have multiple `Person`s associated with it, I'd instead create an `Organization` business object:

```
public record Person(FullName);

public class Organization 
{
    public readonly string Name { get; }
    public readonly Collection<Person> Members { get; }

    public Organization(string name; params string[] members) 
    {
        Name = name?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        foreach (var memberName in members)
        {
            Members.Add(new Person(memberName));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- In this model, each `Organization` has a `Name` and then multiple `Members`—each represented by a `Person` object.
- Because the organization name is handled at the `Organization` level, it is presumably not needed on each `Person` object.
- The `Members` collection could be replaced with a `Collection<string>` if you just need a list of names. But maintaining a `Person` object offers more flexibility.
- You can obviously incorporate the previously proposed validation logic into this constructor as well.
- You could also add an overload of the constructor that accepts a `Person[]` array to offer more flexibility.